# What are the differences between 芸術 (geijutsu) and 美術 (bijutsu)?

Tags: word-choice

What are the differences between 芸術 (geijutsu) and 美術 (bijutsu)?

My native tongue has both of these [Sino-Xenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Xenic_pronunciations) terms too, although in it, the *geijutsu*-word is clearly "art form; art in general; the arts; the humanities" (including literature, music, performance, etc.), while the *bijutsu*-word is clearly "some visual artistic disciplines" (such as drawing, painting, sculpture, architecture, graphic design). No schools of the *bijutsu*-type would offer courses on, say, music. When you say "art for art's sake", you use the *geijutsu*-word. Although I admit that my language may be more under Western influence.

So is that the case with the Japanese words too? Or the differences are something else? Bilingual dictionaries don't seem to be of much help, because it seems like neither of these words actually corresponds to the Western concept of "art", kinda like *kindai* and *gendai* to "modern".

Answer (score 5):

I don't speak Chinese nor Vietnamese, but your explanation is applicable in Japanese too. In short, 美術 is a sub-category of 芸術. 美術 only refers to traditional forms of visual art such as paintings, sculpture, photography and calligraphy. 芸術 also includes music, literature, dance and movie (and probably manga and video games, too).